# Export sql query result to csv from tableau

Tags: csv, tableau-api

I use Tableau soft, i connected to amazon redshift via tableau and created query!
How this query result (10 000 000 obs) export to csv from tableau?
[image: screen example of my table]

Comment: Tableau is not typically used as a querying tool in the fasion you are asking about.  Is there a reason you are unable to you are unable to obtain your csv export directly from redshift? http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/save_export_data.html

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following

1. calculate an aggregate
2. right mouse button
3. See data ...
4. "Complete Data" Option
5. "Export all" option